# For an id if a value is ever false than it's always false SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a data set where I created a value that based on some criteria I get True/False based on some prior values. Now if my member is ever a False they need to have 1 record in which they are always False.  Data is similar to below

```
ID| Indicator
1  | TRUE    
1   | TRUE   
2   | FALSE 
3   | TRUE   
3   | FALSE
```

I want it to look like this

```
ID  |  Indicator
1   |  TRUE
2   | FALSE
3   | FALSE
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in Teradata

Comment: what did yout try?

Comment: Does Teradata support a boolean type?

Comment: I tried using the qualify statement looking at the suggestions I think I over thought this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata does not support a boolean type. So, I will assume the indicator is a string.

In that case, the simplest method is `min()`:

```
select id, min(indicator)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: I went with this answer though I think Yogesh Sharma's would work but it didn't like the CASE WHEN EXISTS syntax. I think if I had a multi select option like True, False, Undecided I would want to use the other one.

Comment: @JacobIan: Don't do the `exists` Scalar Subquery, it's very inefficient compared to aggregation. If you got multiple options you can put in a MIN/MAX(CASE ...)

Answer (score 1):

Based on sample data, i would do :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM table t1 
                          WHERE t1.id = t.id AND t1.Indicator = 'False'
                         ) 
             THEN 'False' 
             ELSE 'TRUE' 
        END) AS Indicator
FROM table t;
```